# Showing image based on which button is pressed in previous VC

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to show an image in the current VC based on which button triggered the segue from the previous VC to the current .. i've tried using both performSegue and prepareSegue and didn't get to do what i want .. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make a variable which you can set to a number then in the new vc check if the var equals 1 set it to one image and then in the other vc put if var = 2 set it to somthing diffrent. Make sure the var is a global

Hope this helps